# regex match all characters after open bracket [

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using a regex

```
/(?<=\[)(.*)/i
```

to match every character after a `[`. A user will type something like:

> hello this is [what i want

I want it it match `what i want`. It seems to work on a regex tester: http://gskinner.com/RegExr. When I use it in my code it doesn't work at all. Is this because I'm not using the right regex flavor? Here is my snippet:

```
var location = document.getElementById('locationField').value=(commandLineInput.match(/(?<=\[)(.*)/i));
```

I just want to make the "location" variable to be all the contents after the `[`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Javascript does not support lookbehind.  BTW why are you using the `i` flag? There are no letters in your regex.

How about:

```
var str  = "hello this is [what i want";
var want = str.match(/\[(.+)$/)[1];
```

instead?

Comment: Which would be a better language to write regex in? I'm not great with anything but HTML really, but I'd like to get into php and javascript heavier - and whatever language I could write regex in w/all options.

Comment: @user Perl has arguably one of the most powerful regex engines out there, but PHP's regex support isn't too bad. JS's regex support is downright terrible.

Comment: I am beginning to feel that JS is exactly that. Thank you for the help, stackoverflow and its community is an amazing help.

Comment: You should make it `str.match(/\[(.+)$/) || [0, ''][1];` just in case there isn't a bracket.

Comment: Is there a way to make it say "if only [ bracket in string" then do as this answer provided - but if "[ and then a ]" bracket, to pull just the contents between the brackets?

Comment: @user Use `/\[(.+)\]?$/` then. The `\]?` means an optional (0 or 1) right bracket.

Comment: @Fabdrol It doesn't, but you can replace the dot with `[\s\S]` if you want to match literally anything